# How to mount the huge tlb (huge page) as a file system?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, cpu-architecture

Here is my machine details (ubuntu):

```
$uname -a
```

Linux rex-think 3.13.0-46-generic #76-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 26 18:52:13 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have enabled huge page in root user with:

```
$echo 20 > /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
```

Now I want to mount huge page as a file system and open it for read/write, e.g., using the C API below

```
#define FILE_NAME "/mnt/hugepages/hello"
fd = open(FILE_NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0755);    // writing to huge page using file sys API
```

But I am not sure how to mount the huge page. In /proc/sys/vm/, I can see

hugetlb_shm_group 
hugepages_treat_as_movable

but from the description [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt), I dont think they are the files I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mount huge tlp as file system use the below command

```
mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /mnt/huge
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have encounter the next problem. Could you also give your feedback here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28826470/mmap-failed-when-trying-to-map-huge-page-1mb